Does SchemaSpy supports Azure Data Warehouse? Any other open-source alternative?
We use azure data warehouse service to store our Datasets which are huge in sizes and I want to check if SchemaSpy tool would be able to help us generate interactive HTML documentation for database schemas or help us visualize and understand the structure, relationships, and constraints within the data.
I reviewed their documentation but didn't find anywhere mentioned about Azure Data warehouse or synapse support.
Can anyone please confirm if they have used this tools on Azure Data warehouse or synapse?
Does it support them or is there any other alternative open-source tool available?

https://dataedo.com/tutorials/create-diagram-for-existing-azure-sql-data-warehouse-database#:~:text=A%20few%20tips%20*%20Keep%20your%20diagrams,Dictionary%20to%20document%20and%20explain%20your%20databases.
